# Player is undefined in update but not in create

Tags: javascript, html

So ive bee trying to start making a little game for fun. The problem is when i make a new player in game object it says it is undefined in update function but is defined in create function.

```
Game.prototype = {
    create: function () {       
        this.player = new Player(this.ctx, this.canvas);
        this.player.create();
        console.log(this.player); // shows the player in console
    },
    update: function () {
        console.log(this.player); //undefined
        this.player.update();
    }
};
```

Here is how i start my game

```
function startGame(){
    var fps = 1;
    var game = new Game();
    game.create();
    setInterval(game.update, 1000/fps);
}
```

error-> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at update (Game.js:19)

Comment: Maybe try `setInterval(function() { game.update() }, 1000/fps)`

Comment: Thanks that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out some code (yours errors I'm pretty sure since `Game` is undefined) but your solution would probably be to change your `setInterval` call like so

```
setInterval(function() { game.update() }, 1000/fps);
```

Using `setInterval(game.update, 1000/fps);` has the somewhat unintuitive side effect of causing the method to be called without the correctly associated `this` since `update` is not being bound to `game` (see Kyle Lin's answer). Basically `update` exists all by itself, and when you create a reference to it directly, the fact that you referenced it via `game.update` is lost.

By using an anonymous function like this, `update` will have the appropriate/expected `this` value when called. This is because we are able to use the explicit syntax `[OBJECT].[MemberMethod]()` implicitly binds `this` to `[OBJECT]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a `setInterval` callback, `this` usually refers to the window. Make sure it refers to its intended target (your game instance), using the `.bind()` method:

```
function startGame(){
  var fps = 1;
  var game = new Game();
  game.create();
  setInterval(game.update.bind(game), 1000/fps);
}
```

For more information on the `.bind()` method, click here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

EDIT:
Even better link on the window timer `this` problem:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#The_this_problem , thanks to Andrew Li.

Comment: Helpful links to add: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#The_this_problem and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem